# How get refs.value in styled-component React?

Tags: reactjs, ref, styled-components

I want get ref value of input, without styled component:

```js
<form  role='form' method='POST' onSubmit= {::this.onSubmit}>               
<input id='name' type='text' ref='name' name='name'  required/>
<button> Register</button></form>


 onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.refs.name.value)...}
```

How get ref.value in styled-component?

```js
  <form  role='form' method='POST' onSubmit= {::this.onSubmit}>               
<StyledInput innerRef={name => { this.input = name }} id='name' type='text' name='name' />
<button> Register</button></form>  

 onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log(this.input);....}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `innerRef={name => { this.input = name }}` makes the input node available through `this.input`

```
console.log(this.input.value)
```

You could get the value from the `Event` without using `ref`

```
onSubmit(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

More details about [React forms.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Demo component:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const InputStyled = styled.input`
  background: lightgreen;
`;

class Test extends React.Component {
  onChange = e => {
    console.log(this.input.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <InputStyled
        onChange={this.onChange}
        innerRef={input => (this.input = input)}
      />
    );
  };
}

export default Test;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how StyledInput works with refs, but you can access a ref node with the .current key of the ref object.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

Answer (score 0):

As of React 16.8.0. with hooks, you can access the reference in the following manner with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) -

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

...

const inputRef = useRef(null);

...

<StyledInput ref={inputRef} />

<Button onClick={()=>{inputRef.current.focus()}}>Focus on input</Button>


...

const StyledInput = styled(input)`
`;

const Button = styled(button)`
`;
```